# Mesh and Armature Problem ( The mesh connected with 0 point coordination)

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature

I was trying to make it (the black line stripe) gone here the pict :

[image]

and this is the hierarchy :

[image]

when i chose my mesh and armature i select parent "with empty group or with automatic weights" the black line stripe added somehow this makes my unity project messed up i want to convert it to unity btw everytime this string or black line exist my unity project was messed up

i want to make it like this :

[image]

and this is the parent hierarchy

[image]

as you can see there is no black line stripe in there and its perfectly works in my unity all i need is black line stripe is gone thats all thank you for answering any valueable answer i really appreciate it thanks !!

Comment: That's just a relationship line showing that the object your character is carrying is parented to your character. You can turn those lines off in the viewport by unchecking Relationship Lines on the [Viewport Overlay menu](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html?utm_source=blender-3.6.2#viewport-overlays).